# Manipulating (subtract or add seconds) Stopwatch.Elapsed in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stopwatch

I need to be able to subtract a couple seconds from my timer for my Selenium performance test in Visual Studio. The following is a sample of my code:

```
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();            
        UploadFiles();
        sw.Stop();

        //Logging of performance results
        Console.WriteLine("The time for ALEX to upload a large data set is {0}", sw.Elapsed);
```

The UploadFiles(); method includes a Sleep of 3 seconds, and it needs to be there for other tests. So removing the sleep is out of the question. I need a way to just subtract 3 seconds from sw.Elapsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract a `TimeSpan` like this:

```
var result = sw.Elapsed - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to use DateTime:

```
var start = DateTime.Now;
UploadFiles();
var end = DateTime.Now;

var elapsed = (end - start - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).TotalSeconds;
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: {0} seconds" + elapsed);
```